# Would Vipera Evanesca work on a Basilisk?

Tags: harry-potter, spells, basilisk

If someone casted Vipera Evanesca on a Basilisk, would it have worked?

Answer (score 5):

## It’s unclear from the known information.

There’s no way of knowing for sure or deducing the likely possibility of what effect, if any, *Vipera Evanesca* would have on a basilisk with the information given.

## Basilisks *are* a type of snake.

Though they’re much larger and more powerful than most snakes, Basilisks are a type of snake. In Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them, Newt classifies them as serpents.

> “The Basilisk is a brilliant green serpent that may reach up to fifty feet in length.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

There are similarities evident between more typical snakes and basilisks. Parseltongue is the language of snakes, and Parselmouths can talk to snakes.

> “I’m a what?’ said Harry.
>
> *‘A Parselmouth!’* said Ron. ‘You can talk to snakes!” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 11 (The Duelling Club)*</sup></sub>

Basilisks can be controlled by Parselmouths, so therefore they speak the same language as typical snakes.

> “However, since Basilisks are uncontrollable except by Parselmouths, they are as dangerous to most Dark wizards as to anybody else, and there have been no recorded sightings of Basilisks in Britain for at least four hundred years.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

Some of the same things that work on snakes work on basilisks, so it’s possible that casting *Vipera Evanesca* to make them disappear might work on basilisks as well.

## But they may be more resistant to magic.

However, though they are a type of snake, basilisks are far more powerful than the average snake. They’re described as having extraordinarily dangerous powers.

> “BASILISK (also known as the King of Serpents)
>   
> *M.O.M. Classification: XXXXX*
>
> The first recorded Basilisk was bred by Herpo the Foul, a Greek Dark wizard and Parselmouth, who discovered after much experimentation that a chicken egg hatched beneath a toad would produce a gigantic serpent possessed of extraordinarily dangerous powers.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Fantastic Beasts and Where to Find Them*</sup></sub>

Most other creatures with a Ministry classification of XXXXX (known wizard killer/impossible to train or domesticate) have a certain level of resistance to magic. As an example, dragons can’t be knocked out by one Stunning Spell - it takes several wizards casting spells to effectively overcome a dragon.

> “There’s a way, Harry. Don’t be tempted to try a Stunning Spell – dragons are strong and too powerfully magical to be knocked out by a single Stunner. You need about half-a-dozen wizards at a time to overcome a dragon –” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Goblet of Fire, Chapter 19 (The Hungarian Horntail)*</sup></sub>

Similarly, it may not be so simple to make a basilisk disappear with one spell,  if it’d work at all. Even if *Vipera Evanesca* would work on a basilisk, it might take several to make it vanish.

---

## But - the spell may not exist in the book.

The above answer pertains to the spell *Vipera Evanesca* as seen in the movie version of Chamber of Secrets. However, that’s *not* necessarily what Snape did in the book. In the book, Snape wordlessly makes the snake vanish - the incantation isn’t said.

> “Snape stepped forward, waved his wand and the snake vanished in a small puff of black smoke.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Chamber of Secrets, Chapter 11 (The Duelling Club)*</sup></sub>

In the book, Snape may have simply been vanishing a conjured object, which is likely fairly easy as conjured objects don’t last anyway. He also could have cast Evanesco nonverbally. In the book, there might not even be a spell meant specifically for vanishing snakes, so any attempt to vanish a basilisk may have to be done with *Evanesco*. That’d be extremely difficult, as more complex animals are increasingly harder to vanish than simpler creatures.

> “Looking supremely unconcerned, Professor McGonagall addressed the class once more.
>   ‘As I was saying: the Vanishing Spell becomes more difficult with the complexity of the animal to be Vanished. The snail, as an invertebrate, does not present much of a challenge; the mouse, as a mammal, offers a much greater one. This is not, therefore, magic you can accomplish with your mind on your dinner. So – you know the incantation, let me see what you can do …” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 15 (The Hogwarts High Inquisitor)*</sup></sub>

In that case, trying to vanish a basilisk is likely to be extremely difficult, as they’re extraordinarily powerful and very large.

Comment: We know that it is most likely Vipera Evanesca anyway because the Wikia page for that spell says so (see my answer).

Comment: @InventPalooza The wiki page isn’t always accurate since anyone can edit it with their personal opinions. Also, presumably the reason it says that is *because* Vipera Evanesca was used in the movie, which *doesn’t* mean it was the spell used in the book.

Comment: Very true... However, I believe we can still make the assumption that it is true.

Comment: Also, it doesn’t necessarily have to be the same incantation. We know from the book that Professor Snape was able to vanish the snake that Malfoy had conjured. Therefore, there must be such a spell existing in the Harry Potter universe and the OP’s intent should be maintained.

Answer (score 1):

## In theory, yes...

According to Wikia:

> The Snake-Vanishing Spell (Vipera Evanesca) is a spell that vanishes snakes.
>   https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Snake-Vanishing_Spell

from their page on *Vipera Evanesca*.

From their page on the Basilisk:

> The Basilisk is a giant serpent, also known as the King of Serpents. 
>   https://harrypotter.fandom.com/wiki/Basilisk

This means that it should be able to work. However, Harry was very inexperienced with magic, but Snape was not. Therefore, it makes sense that Harry would not have used that because it was a very high-level spell, and he likely hadn't heard of it at the time.

Comment: It would be helpful to link the source of your quotes.